# Jetpack Compose collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I can't find any documents on the matter, is there something similar to a `CollapsingToolbar` in Compose?

All I found was a mention of it [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures), but nothing on how to set it up

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Jetpack Compose implementation of **Material Design 3** includes 4 types of Top App Bars (https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/implementation):

- `CenterAlignedTopAppBar`
- `SmallTopAppBar`
- `MediumTopAppBar`
- `LargeTopAppBar`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary

They all have a `scrollBehavior` parameter, which can be used for collapsing the toolbar. There are 3 basic types of scroll behavior in the library:

- `TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior`
- `TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior`
- `TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TopAppBarDefaults

**Note:** This API is annotated as experimental at the moment.

#### Sample usage:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            MediumTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Scroll Behavior Test") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu, contentDescription = "")
                    }
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            items((1..50).toList()) { item ->
                Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), text = "Item $item")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the latest version of Compose, the `enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()` gives an error: `No value passed for parameter 'state'`. You may update your example.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the example.

Comment: Is it just me or is there no way to increase the maximum height for these toolbars? For example, seems like `LargeTopAppBar` maxes out at `TopAppBarLargeTokens.ContainerHeight` (ie. `152 dp`). Anyone aware of a way past this limitation? Or does that mean that I'll have to pass on these Material 3 toolbars at the moment?

Comment: When using a `LargeTopAppBar`, is there a way to customize it so when it is in the tall state (ie. dragged down), to show completely different composables than when it's in the smaller/collapsed state?

Comment: @Manveru Perhaps you know how to fix my issue, could you take a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326733/collapsingtoolbar-in-compose-with-button-sticky

Comment: What if I don't have a lazyColumn and have scrollable views (Column)

Answer (score 20):

I found a solution created by Samir Basnet (from Kotlin Slack Channel) which was useful for me, I hope it helps someone else...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CollapsingEffectScreen() {
    val items = (1..100).map { "Item $it" }
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    var scrolledY = 0f
    var previousOffset = 0
    LazyColumn(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        lazyListState,
    ) {
        item {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.recife),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        scrolledY += lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset - previousOffset
                        translationY = scrolledY * 0.5f
                        previousOffset = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
                    }
                    .height(240.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
        items(items) {
            Text(
                text = it,
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Here is the slack message link if anyone needs it: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1617182855437800

Comment: Here is the slack message link if anyone needs it: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1617182855437800

Comment: This solution is helpful and different from the Android Doc's collapsing toolbar example because it only allows the collapsed item to be expanded if the list is at the top.  Thank you for this answer

Comment: does it scroll from the top image also?

Comment: What if the content is hybrid, i.e. the top image (or toolbar) in native xml and remaining layout (LazyColumn) in jetpack compose??

Answer (score 15):

I found this in Android docs, I think the documentation you linked in the question is talking about doing it like this with nested scrolling.

```
val toolbarHeight = 48.dp
    val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { toolbarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
    val toolbarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {

                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
                toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-toolbarHeightPx, 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()

            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {

        LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = toolbarHeight)) {
            items(100) { index ->
                Text("I'm item $index", modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp))
            }
        }
        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(toolbarHeight)
                .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) },
            title = { Text("toolbar offset is ${toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value}") }
        )
    }
```

Comment: This solution will collapse and expand the toolbar anytime the list is scrolled up or down.  See @nglauber answer if you want the toolbar to expand only if the list is scrolled to the top

Comment: Thanks for this example. For the record, it can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [compose-collapsing-toolbar](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar) library.

**Instalation** : `implementation "me.onebone:toolbar-compose:2.1.0"`

[Usage](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar#usage) - [Exemple](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar/blob/master/app/src/main)

###### Preview

Here are some gif images from the Readme.md of the library:

[image: jetpack compose collapsing toolbar]
[image: jetpack compose collapsing toolbar | EnterAlwaysCollapsed]
[image: jetpack compose collapsing toolbar | ExitUntilCollapsed]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [example in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).nestedScroll(androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollDispatcher)) to create a toolbar which expands/collapses on every scroll up/down.

To create a toolbar which expands only when the list is scrolled to the top, you can make a slight adaptation to the original example:

```
val toolbarHeight = 48.dp
val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { toolbarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
var toolbarOffsetHeightPx by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var totalScrollOffsetPx = remember { 0f }

val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {

            val delta = available.y
            totalScrollOffsetPx += delta
            
            if (totalScrollOffsetPx in -toolbarHeightPx..0f) {
                toolbarOffsetHeightPx = totalScrollOffsetPx
            }

            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

By doing so, you have a flexibility which would enable you to create your own `CollapsibleScaffold` which could accept params like `scrollBehaviour`, `appBarLayout` and `list` composables etc.

That way, for instance, you could also programmatically calculate the height of the app bar and get rid of the high amount of boilerplate, making the code used in your screens neat and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used to create Collapsing Effect in compose

- `Constraint layout - compose`
  To create constraint sets using .json5 file. Create start, end and transition effect in between.
- `Motion Layout` Add all widgets to motion layout in compose function.
- Identify the progress of the scroll in list.

**RESULT + [Source Code](https://github.com/arpit999/ComposeDemo/tree/collapsing_toolbar)**

[image: Collapsing Toolbar]

Add this dependency.

> `implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha03")`

**`STEP 1:`** Create `collapse_toolbar.json5` file in raw resource folder.

**collapse_toolbar.json5**

```
    {
  ConstraintSets: {
    start: {
      box: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 230,
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['parent', 'top'],
        custom: {
          background: '#FF74d680'
        }
      },
      help_image:{
        width: 80,
        height: 120,
        end: ['box', 'end', 16],
        top: ['box', 'top', 16],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom',8]
      },
      close_button:{
        start: ['parent', 'start',8],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom',8]
      },
      title: {
        start: ['close_button', 'end', 16],
        bottom: ['close_button', 'bottom'],
        top: ['close_button', 'top']
      }

    },
    end: {
      help_image:{
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom'],
        end: ['box', 'end']
      },
      box: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 56,
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['parent', 'top'],
        custom: {
          background: '#FF378b29'
        }
      },
      close_button:{
        start: ['box', 'start', 16],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom', 16],
        top: ['box', 'top', 16]
      },
      title: {
        start: ['close_button', 'end', 8],
        bottom: ['close_button', 'bottom'],
        top: ['close_button', 'top']
      }

    }
  },
  Transitions: {
    default: {
      from: 'start',
      to: 'end',
      pathMotionArc: 'startVertical',
      // key here must be Key with capital K
      KeyFrames: {
        KeyAttributes: [
          {
            target: ['box'],
            frames: [0, 20, 50, 80, 100]
//            rotationZ: [0,  360]
          },
          {
            target: ['close_button'],
            frames: [0, 20, 60, 80, 100],
//            translationY: [20, 40, 65, 85, 100]
//            alpha: [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1]
          },
          {
            target: ['title'],
            frames: [0, 100],
//            translationY: [20,100]
//            alpha: [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1]
          },
          {
            target: ['help_image'],
            frames: [0, 30, 50, 80, 100],
            scaleX: [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0],
            scaleY: [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0],
            alpha: [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**`STEP 2:`** Create composable function and add `Motion Layout`

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val lazyScrollState = rememberLazyListState()
            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                topBar = {
                    CollapsingToolbar(lazyScrollState)
                },
            ) { paddingValues ->
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
                    LazyColumn(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(color = Color.White)
                            .animateContentSize(),
                        state = lazyScrollState
                    ) {
                        items(100) { index ->
                            Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(36.dp), text = "Item: $index")
                            Divider(color = Color.Black, thickness = 1.dp)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun CollapsingToolbar(lazyScrollState: LazyListState) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.collapse_toolbar).readBytes().decodeToString()
    }

    val progress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex in 0..1) 0f else 1f,
        tween(500)
    )
    val motionHeight by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex in 0..1) 230.dp else 56.dp,
        tween(500)
    )

    MotionLayout(
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
        progress = progress,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .height(motionHeight)
    ) {

        val boxProperties = motionProperties(id = "box")
//        val startColor = Color(boxProperties.value.color("custome"))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("box")
                .background(boxProperties.value.color("background"))
        )

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("help_image"),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.help),
            contentDescription = ""
        )

        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("close_button"),
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close,
            contentDescription = "",
            tint = Color.White
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("title"),
            text = "Help",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: if u remove padding on Text i mean here  Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(36.dp), text = "Item: $index")   collapsing toolbar not wors

Answer (score 0):

I had some specific needs so I've created a simple impl which measure navigationIcons and Trainling icons and try to fit the content between them.
Ignoring overloads and test code, it's less than 200 lines, should be pretty simple to customize for your specific needs.

https://gist.github.com/fabriciovergara/5de1e8b114fb484bf5f6808a0a107b24

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CollapsibleScaffold(
    state: LazyListState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable (insets: PaddingValues) -> Unit
) {
    CollapsibleScaffoldInternal(
        offsetState = rememberOffsetScrollState(state),
        modifier = modifier,
        topBar = topBar,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
private fun CollapsibleScaffoldInternal(
    offsetState: State<Int>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable (insets: PaddingValues) -> Unit
) {
    Scaffold(modifier = modifier, backgroundColor = Color.Transparent) { insets ->
        Box {
            content(
                PaddingValues(
                    top = CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.maxHeight + 8.dp,
                    bottom = 16.dp
                )
            )
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalScrollOffset provides offsetState,
                LocalInsets provides insets
            ) {
                topBar()
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun CollapsibleTopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    actions: (@Composable RowScope.() -> Unit)? = null,
    navigationIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    content: (@Composable CollapsibleTopAppBarScope.() -> Unit) = { }
) {
    CollapsibleTopAppBarInternal(
        scrollOffset = LocalScrollOffset.current.value,
        insets = LocalInsets.current,
        modifier = modifier.background(Color.Transparent),
        navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
        actions = actions,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
private fun CollapsibleTopAppBarInternal(
    scrollOffset: Int,
    insets: PaddingValues,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    actions: (@Composable RowScope.() -> Unit)? = null,
    content: @Composable CollapsibleTopAppBarScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val actionsSize = remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    val navIconSize = remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    val actionWidth = with(density) { actionsSize.value.width.toDp() }
    val backWidth = with(density) { navIconSize.value.width.toDp() }
    val bodyHeight = CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.maxHeight - CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.minHeight
    val maxOffset = with(density) {
        bodyHeight.roundToPx() - insets.calculateTopPadding().roundToPx()
    }

    val offset = min(scrollOffset, maxOffset)
    val fraction = 1f - kotlin.math.max(0f, offset.toFloat()) / maxOffset
    val currentMaxHeight = bodyHeight * fraction

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = modifier) {
        val maxWidth = maxWidth
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.minHeight)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                    navIconSize.value = it.size
                }
            ) {
                if (navigationIcon != null) {
                    navigationIcon()
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .widthIn(0.dp, maxWidth / 3)
                    .onGloballyPositioned { actionsSize.value = it.size }
            ) {
                if (actions != null) {
                    actions()
                }
            }
        }

        val scaleFraction = (fraction / CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.startScalingFraction).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
        val paddingStart = if (fraction > CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.startScalingFraction) {
            0.dp
        } else {
            lerp(backWidth, 0.dp, scaleFraction)
        }

        val paddingEnd = if (fraction > CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.startScalingFraction) {
            0.dp
        } else {
            lerp(actionWidth, 0.dp, scaleFraction)
        }

        /**
         *  When content height reach minimum size, we start translating it to fit the toolbar
         */
        val startTranslateFraction = CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.minHeight / CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.maxHeight
        val translateFraction = (fraction / startTranslateFraction).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
        val paddingTop = if (fraction > startTranslateFraction) {
            CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.minHeight
        } else {
            lerp(0.dp, CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.minHeight, translateFraction)
        }

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = paddingTop, start = paddingStart, end = paddingEnd)
                .height(max(CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults.minHeight, currentMaxHeight))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
        ) {
            val scope = remember(fraction, this) {
                CollapsibleTopAppBarScope(fraction = fraction, scope = this)
            }
            content(scope)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun rememberOffsetScrollState(state: LazyListState): MutableState<Int> {
    val offsetState = rememberSaveable() { mutableStateOf(0) }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo) {
        val fistItem = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == 0 }
        val offset = fistItem?.offset?.absoluteValue ?: Int.MAX_VALUE
        offsetState.value = offset
    }
    return offsetState
}


object CollapsibleTopAppBarDefaults {
    // Replicating the value in androidx.compose.material.AppBar.AppBarHeight which is private
    val minHeight = 56.dp
    val maxHeight = 320.dp

    /**
     *  When content height reach this point we start applying padding start and end
     */
    const val startScalingFraction = 0.5f
}
```

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can check the working of nested scroll over here:- https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/nestedscroll/package-summary In this if you have a full scroll list, i.e, you know that your list will have enough items to make it scrollable then use only nested scroll connection. But you have finite items and your list might have very few items, and sometimes it might not be scrollable, then in that case use nestedScrollConnection with nestedScrollDispatcher. With the second option, it implements drag as well as scroll for the list. So the drag will happen until your toolbar reaches its minimum height and then list will be scrollable only after that.

Over here I have done the simple implementation of collapsing toolbar using this.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CoordinatorLayoutComposeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
                        CoordinatorLayout()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Composable
    fun CoordinatorLayout() {
        // Let's take Modifier.draggable (which doesn't have nested scroll build in, unlike Modifier
// .scrollable) and add nested scroll support our component that contains draggable

// this will be a generic components that will work inside other nested scroll components.
// put it inside LazyColumn or / Modifier.verticalScroll to see how they will interact

// first, state and it's bounds
        val basicState = remember { mutableStateOf(200f) }
        val minBound = 60f
        val maxBound = 200f
// lambda to update state and return amount consumed
        val onNewDelta: (Float) -> Float = { delta ->
            val oldState = basicState.value
            val newState = (basicState.value + delta).coerceIn(minBound, maxBound)
            basicState.value = newState
            newState - oldState
        }
// create a dispatcher to dispatch nested scroll events (participate like a nested scroll child)
        val nestedScrollDispatcher = remember { NestedScrollDispatcher() }

// create nested scroll connection to react to nested scroll events (participate like a parent)
        val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
            object : NestedScrollConnection {
                override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    val vertical = available.y
                    val weConsumed = onNewDelta(vertical)
                    return Offset(x = 0f, y = weConsumed)
                }
            }
        }
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .nestedScroll(connection = nestedScrollConnection, dispatcher = nestedScrollDispatcher)
                .draggable(
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                        // here's regular drag. Let's be good citizens and ask parents first if they
                        // want to pre consume (it's a nested scroll contract)
                        val parentsConsumed = nestedScrollDispatcher.dispatchPreScroll(
                            available = Offset(x = 0f, y = delta),
                            source = NestedScrollSource.Drag
                        )
                        // adjust what's available to us since might have consumed smth
                        val adjustedAvailable = delta - parentsConsumed.y
                        // we consume
                        val weConsumed = onNewDelta(adjustedAvailable)
                        // dispatch as a post scroll what's left after pre-scroll and our consumption
                        val totalConsumed = Offset(x = 0f, y = weConsumed) + parentsConsumed
                        val left = adjustedAvailable - weConsumed
                        nestedScrollDispatcher.dispatchPostScroll(
                            consumed = totalConsumed,
                            available = Offset(x = 0f, y = left),
                            source = NestedScrollSource.Drag
                        )
                    }
                )
        ) {
            LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = basicState.value.dp)) {
                items(100) { index ->
                    Text("I'm item $index", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp))
                }
            }
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(basicState.value.dp),
                title = { Text("toolbar offset is ${basicState.value}") }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a gif of how the collapsing top bar is working, the lag you see is not because of app, but of recording the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWM3Z.gif)

Answer (score -1):

Compose-collapsing-toolbar
A simple implementation of CollapsingToolbarLayout for Jetpack Compose

https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29883520)

Answer (score -1):

@Manveru answer above worked well with `Scaffold` however it does not cover how to support custom topbars. Here is the minimum you need to get a topbar to **fully** collapse in a scaffold.

#1) Add a scroll behavior to the Scaffold, in this case an enter always behavior:

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
```

#2) For the `Scaffold` add `nestedScroll` to modifier.

```
Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
```

#3) Add custom top bar to `topBar` slot. (from [AppBar.kt](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/AppBar.kt))

```
val heightOffsetLimit = with(LocalDensity.current) { -64.dp.toPx() }

SideEffect {
    if (scrollBehavior.state.heightOffsetLimit != heightOffsetLimit) {
        scrollBehavior.state.heightOffsetLimit = heightOffsetLimit
    }
}

val heightPx = LocalDensity.current.run {
    64.dp.toPx() + scrollBehavior.state.heightOffset
}

val height = LocalDensity.current.run {
    heightPx.toDp()
}

Box(modifier = Modifier.height(height)) {
    // app bar here
}
```

#4) To content slot add either `LazyColumn` described in @Manveru's answer or add a `Column` with `verticalScroll` modifier.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(padding)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    // column here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll leave this code here for anyone looking for a **fast** and **simple** solution to hide a `Toolbar`, `TopAppBar`, or some sort of header.

```
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            // Track LazyColumn scroll:
            val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

            // Keep index of first visible item in list:
            val firstVisibleItemIndex by remember { derivedStateOf { lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex } }

            // Keep the toolbar visibility state:
            var displayToolbar by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

            // Here we decide to only display toolbar when we are at the top of the list:
            displayToolbar = firstVisibleItemIndex == 0

            // Toolbar
            AnimatedVisibility(visible = displayToolbar) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp)) 
            }

            // List
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f, false),
                state = lazyListState
            ) {
                items((1..100).toList()) { item ->
                    Text(text = "$item")
                }
            }

        }
```

In this method, we want to show (or expand) the toolbar when we are at the top of the list and hide (or collapse) it when we are not at the very top. Therefore, we should check the index of the first item visible in the list and toggle the visibility of the toolbar based on it. I have used `AnimatedVisibility` to change the visibility with a smooth animation.

Comment: This isn't a Collapsing Toolbar Behaviour. This is something one shouldn't do as a developer.

Comment: Let me share some wisdom that can be beneficial for you. Our choice of programming languages, SDKs, and frameworks is akin to a carpenter's tools when crafting with wood, they offer us creative possibilities. Especially when there are no performance or memory concerns, developers have the freedom to use these tools creatively. I've introduced a simple solution that resembles CollapsingToolbar and can cater to the needs of many developers without any adverse effects. Let's embrace diversity in approaches and keep spreading positivity in our community! @KishanSolanki