# Can LazyColumn work along with CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coordinator-layout

I am migrating an app to Jetpack Compose and I have the following situation on a view/compose hybrid screen:

- The layout root element is a CoordinatorLayout that has a top bar which is collapsible.
- The content is a FragmentViewPager, and one of the pages is the Fragment I am migrating to Compose.
- When I scroll the LazyColumn inside this fragment, the top bar won't collapse/expand.

My question is: Can I do something to make both pieces work together? i.e: When I scroll a LazyColumn, a CoordinatorLayout that contains it will make it's top bar collapse/expand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227755/jetpack-compose-collapsing-toolbar

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure this is what I am after. This seems to a be a way to implement a collapsing toolbar behavior in compose. What I am looking for is a way to make the LazyColumn work with an actual CoordinatorLayout on a hybrid implementation.  I need this because I am migrating the screen and reimplementing the whole thing would be undoable atm.

Comment: Hey @BrenoBridges - I currently have the same UX bug with an Android CoordinatorLayout and Compose LazyColumn interop architecture. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Compose Interop Android Documentation was recently updated with a subsection on [Nested Scrolling With Views](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui#nested-scrolling). At this time, Android `CoordinatorLayout` and Compose `LazyColumn` interop UX is not officially supported. The official Google Issue Tracker is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/174348612).

Comment: Solution by Chris Banes mentioned inside helped me straight away. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Przemo How did you implement fling? I used the same solution but fling is not working correctly.

Comment: I didn't. I realized later that sth is wrong with flinging, but haven't been working on it yet. If you find solution, please share.

Comment: @PrzemekTom can you share with me the workaround? I tried to check Chris Banes solution but apparently he deleted the gist.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access anymore. But be aware that at that time there was still the fling issue.