# CenterAlignedTopAppBar scrollBehavior: No value passed for parameter 'state'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I saw that a new parameter has recently been added to the Material3 Top App Bar Composables on Jetpack Compose:

```
fun CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    ...
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null
) {}
```

What I understood from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#CenterAlignedTopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)) is that this should enable us to implement the behaviour that the app bar hides at scrolling the content. However, I did not manage to implement this, as the only example I found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366197/8331157) seems to no longer work on the latest version of Jetpack Compose and is giving the error `No value passed for parameter 'state'`.

Can anybody provide an example? 
 What I want to achieve is a `Scaffold`, where as `topBar` a `CenterAlignedTopAppBar` is provided, that scrolls out on top of the screen if the scrollable `content` of the `Scaffold` is scrolled.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work:

```
val topAppBarScrollState: TopAppBarScrollState = rememberTopAppBarScrollState()
val scrollBehavior = remember { TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(topAppBarScrollState) }

CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = titleResource)) },
        actions = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Settings,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        },
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
```

This only seems to be necessary since Compose version `1.2.0-rc02` though, as on older versions the solution in the post linked in my answer still works.