# CenterAlignedTopAppBar won't scroll. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to add a scrollable behavior to the topBar parameter of Scaffold. In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#CenterAlignedTopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)) it says, that I can add the scrollable behavior by setting the CenterAlignedTopAppBar parameter `scrollBehavior`. However it doesn't seem to work.

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824373/centeralignedtopappbar-scrollbehavior-no-value-passed-for-parameter-state) from StackOverflow didn't help.

Any advice appreciated.

Here is how my code goes.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val topAppBarScrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(
        rememberTopAppBarState(),
        { true },
        spring(Spring.StiffnessMediumLow),
        rememberSplineBasedDecay()
    )
    val scrollBehavior = remember { topAppBarScrollBehavior }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            ThemedTopBar(scrollBehavior, title = "Select Guests", onBack = {/* TODO */})
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        //MainContent(innerPadding) 
      }
}

@Composable
fun ThemedTopBar(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior, title: String, onBack: () -> Unit) {
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(51.dp)
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 9.dp)
        ,
        title = {
            Text(
                text = title,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                style = Typography.titleMedium
            )
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(
                modifier = Modifier.size(22.dp),
                onClick = onBack,
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back),
                    contentDescription = "Back Button",
                    tint = ThemeBlue
                )
            }
        },
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach the **`TopAppBarScrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection`** to a `Modifier.nestedScroll` in order to keep track of the scroll events.

Something like:

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = { /* .. */ },
            navigationIcon = { /* .. */ },
            actions = { /* .. */ },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
        )
    },
    content = { /* .. */ }
)
```

[image]