# Implement CollapsingToolbar using Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement collapsing toolbar in my Detail screen using Jetpack compose.

```
val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        278.dp.roundToPx().toFloat()
    }
    val toolbarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
                toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-toolbarHeightPx, 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            // attach as a parent to the nested scroll system
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        DetailsContent(
            scrollState = scrollState,
            onNamePosition = { newNamePosition ->
                // Comparing to Float.MIN_VALUE as we are just interested on the original
                // position of name on the screen
                if (detailScroller.namePosition == Float.MIN_VALUE) {
                    detailScroller =
                        detailScroller.copy(namePosition = newNamePosition)
                }
            },
            item = item,
            boxHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                440.dp + toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.toDp()
            },
            imageHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                420.dp + toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.toDp()
            },
            sendNotification = sendNotification,
            contentAlpha = { contentAlpha.value }
        )
        DetailsToolbar(
            toolbarState, item.name, pressOnBack,
            contentAlpha = { contentAlpha.value }
        )
    }
```

The idea is taken from sunflower Google Github project. When we scroll up it works as expected but when we scroll down, it will not sometimes fully scrolled. `toolbarOffsetHeightPx` should become 0 when we scroll down, but sometimes it is a negative value that cause image does not fully scrolled. It is not stable at all and 0 or any negative value may happen. it happens since we have :

```
boxHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                440.dp + toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.toDp()
            },
imageHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                420.dp + toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.toDp()
            }
```

Why is that and how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you check if this answer helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227755/jetpack-compose-collapsing-toolbar/67248441#67248441

Comment: @nglauber it does not help, because I am displaying a toolbar when we scroll up which does not considered in your sample. Also I do not have a list rather an image and TextView.

Comment: @Ali Perhaps you know how to fix my issue, could you take a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326733/collapsingtoolbar-in-compose-with-button-sticky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported it as a minor bug in issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238177355

***Update***

The issue is now fixed and you can find my solution here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/Compose-CollapsingToolbar