# How to hide or expand Topbar from Scaffold in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, vertical-scrolling

I have a custom topbar view added under a Scaffold. How do I achieve the following behaviour of TopBar which is part of Scaffold in Jetpack compose android. (At least the hiding part if expanding is not possible)

[image: Hiding and expanding topbar while scrolling]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at this [project](https://github.com/android/sunflower/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/compose/plantdetail) source. `PlantDetailView.kt` implementation is similar to what you want in detail.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227755/jetpack-compose-collapsing-toolbar)