# Animated Sticky Header with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am new to jetpack compose and would like to implement an animated sticky header.

The general animation is as such: When you start to scroll the list, the header translates upwards with nice smooth animation from current height to fixed min height based on scrolling list’s scroll value and sticks on the top of the screen. This video shows an example of the animated header https://youtu.be/1vt3uCq_Y1g?si=pykTmv1EpjHuW-iS

I currently have a Lazy Column that consists of cards. How should i track the scroll offset and have the header translate upwards?

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227755/jetpack-compose-collapsing-toolbar

Comment: @JosueMuleshi It is different as the app bar collapses in that case. I want my header to scroll to a minHeight